# Regular expression that matches only the last occurrence of a specified character

Tags: regex, plsql

I need to create a regular expression in order to use to remove the last comma from a dynamic SQL create table statement. My query basically picks up all column names, and the table name and returns something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( column1 DATATYPE(1), column2 DATATYPE(20),);
```

I concatenated commas to all after the data_length specification, because it would be easier to just remove the last comma afterward. I'm using `REGEXP_REPLACE` to do that, however since Oracle doesn't support lookahead or lookbehind, then I cannot use this expression which was working fine:

```
\,(?=[);])\
```

So instead I've got this other expression:

```
\(\);)?,\
```

but it is not precise enough because it takes all the commas before the ");", I need it to get the last comma in the create table statement.

I'm using PLSQL for this.

Comment: Since the regex engine matches *greedy*, I would try \\(,)\\);\

Comment: Almost, but no, it matches ',);'

Comment: The comma is in capturing group 1, but btw, why don't you simply replace `,);` by `);` ? That's all.

Comment: I did not consider that, I guess its probably easier to do that than to continue with this hassle. I don't suppose there's a way to put the comment as an answer is there?

Comment: Can you test it? I've unfortunately no testing environment. (Plus you didn't named the programming language ;) (please add that) If it works, I would make and answer out of it.

Comment: I tested it, but not with the language I'm using. I'm using PLSQL for this so I guess that's the language.

Comment: Ok, it should work in any regex language. Let me add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about simply replacing `,);` by `);`? This would effectively remove the last comma before the closing parenthesis.